# What is the difference between "vote" and "no answers" tabs in Unanswered tab?

Tags: discussion, support

Look at the image:

[image]

On hovering over each, it quoted following meaning:

- 'Votes' tab: Highest voted unanswered question
- 'no answers' tab: Questions with no answers

But it appears that 'no answers' tab has question ordered according to highest votes only. Then what is the difference between the two?